# How to use regular expression for a specific number of a first charecte of decimal in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a task to find out a regular expression for bellow case

first digit of a decimal must be number 1 only and the total value of the decimal should not exceed value 1.

eg

```
1.23,
1.99,
1.45,
1.6789432456
```

above are valid cases,and bellow are not valid cases

```
2.34,
4.3456789,
101.222,
11.1233
```

Kindly help me on the above case pls

Comment: What about `105E-2m` ?

Comment: is `1` avlid a valid result?

Comment: (Try)Parse to decimal and then: `value >= 1m && value < 2m`?

Comment: something like :``^1(.)(\d*)``

Comment: what do you mean by _and the total value of the decimal should not exceed value 1_

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
^1\.\d*$
```

[DEMO Working Example](https://regex101.com/r/hF1sN0/2)

Comment: that matches `1x` you have to escape the `.`

Comment: replace `.` with `\.`

Comment: i got it, just tested it by putting x, but why it is macthing with x. Can you tell @fubo?

Comment: `.` is a placeholder for almost any character

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^1\.[\d]*$
```

Matches 1 followed by dot and any number of digits.

Comment: . matches any character. If you want to match it only to dot, you need to escape it.

Comment: ok i go it , **.** is not considered as a literal in this case, so we need to escape it